# z-index IE7, IE8, IE9 doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, input, z-index

The `z-index` CSS property doesn't work on Internet Explorer 7, 8 and 9. How can I workaround this problem?

### HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="text">
    <span>label</span>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
body{background:#ddd;}
div{
    position:relative;
    width:250px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #666;
    z-index:0;
}
input{
    background:none;
    border:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:242px;
    height:22px;
    padding:4px;
    z-index:2;
    *line-height:30px; /* ie7 needs this */
    line-height /*\**/: 30px\9; /* ie8 needs this */
}
span{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:4px;
    z-index:1;
}
input:focus + span{
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -khtml-opacity: 0.50;
    -moz-opacity: 0.50;
    opacity: 0.50;
}
```

If you click on the label, the input doesn't focus

You can see what happens here: http://jsfiddle.net/YKFuZ/2/

Answer (score 2):

I've updated your code a bit - http://jsfiddle.net/YKFuZ/6/

IE doesn't render `z-index` properly. So set your `div`'s Position to absolute. And IE doesn't support the `:focus` pseudo-selector. I would stick to javascript whenever IE is concerned.

**EDIT:** The input's parent is set to relative whereas the input element itself is set to absolute. `Z-index` will not be properly rendered in such a case.

Comment: Works fine in IE8. What browser do you have? I am quite sure that the zindex problem would have been resolved!

Comment: i tried it on ie7, ie8, ie9.. if you click above "label" the input doesnt focus.. try

Comment: Thats weird because the z-index problem is solved for me. Check out my fiddle again. The focus problem requires javascript as that selector is not supported in IE.

Comment: i know but, again, when i click above label the input doesn't select >_> (anyway thanks!)

Comment: oh yes man! i know! it works xD but i meant the problem is when i click above "label".. understand? (i'm sorry for my english lol).. if you click on the next of "label" the input selects, but if you click above "label" input doesn't select, so, it is my z-index problem :D

Comment: I tested on IE8, no focus when click the "label"

Comment: Update the link: version 9 seems to work, but it does bother me that the "label" is still visible on top so you cannot read the text IN the box http://jsfiddle.net/YKFuZ/9/

Comment: @Mark - My answer asked the OP to make the parent's position absolute. Which is what i had done in ver 6 too :| Weird!

Comment: yes it's so weird! ie sucks! ...anyway im working on inputs like twitter sign up

Comment: anyway, thanks to you guys, i think i'll make these input without span absolute, and i'll use <input type="text" value="label">.. it's simpler :)